# Spyne Fault - HTTP Return Codes

Tags: python, http, exception, spyne

I have read information on Spyne Faults (http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/manual/03_types.html), but cant get my head around raising a Fault properly with a 400 Return code. I have the Fault response forming properly, but with a 500 HTTP return code when I have a requirement to return 400.

```
@srpc(Boolean, _returns=String)
def requestConfiguration(value):
    #if value is true, get all the data
    if value == True:
        #todo - get the config
        return 'True Received'

    else:
        # if anything other than True is received, MUST respond with a SOAP fault and HTTP 400
        raise Fault(faultcode="Client.", faultstring="Value must be True")
        # raise error.InvalidInputError("problem", "problem")
```

Reading some of the documentation (http://spyne.io/docs/2.10/modules/spyne/model/fault.html#Fault) , i am interpreting it as the FaultCode must be a string starting with Client and it will return a 400 error. (I know if-else is bad, im just trying to get a proof of concept working before i write the code up properly)

I think i need to subclass the fault instead of just raising it but cant get my head around it. I dived into the code /protocol/soap/soap11 and saw that the fault_to_http_reponse_code simply returns HTTP 500.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I gave up on the subclass approach, instead i just updated the fault_to_http_reponse_code function in soap11.py. Its a gross patch but it does the job for what i want.

```
def fault_to_http_response_code(self, fault):
    from spyne.const.http import HTTP_400, HTTP_401, HTTP_404, HTTP_405, HTTP_413, HTTP_500
    from spyne.error import Fault, InternalError, ResourceNotFoundError, RequestTooLongError, RequestNotAllowed, InvalidCredentialsError
    if isinstance(fault, RequestTooLongError):
        return HTTP_413
    if isinstance(fault, ResourceNotFoundError):
        return HTTP_404
    if isinstance(fault, RequestNotAllowed):
        return HTTP_405
    if isinstance(fault, InvalidCredentialsError):
        return HTTP_401
    if isinstance(fault, Fault) and (fault.faultcode.startswith('Client.')
                                            or fault.faultcode == 'Client'):
        return HTTP_400

    return HTTP_500
```

Then im just raising a normal fault, with the faultcode beginning with Client.

```
raise Fault(faultcode="Client.", faultstring="value must be True)
```

Hopfully someone will chip in with the proper approach to this.

Answer (score 0):

This code returns 401:

```
ctx.transport.respond(HTTP_401)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35141516)